# Cassandra "nodetool status" fails with "Credentials required" after enabling remote JMX

Tags: cassandra, jmx

I followed these instructions "Enabling JMX authentication":

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/configuration/secureJmxAuthentication.html

However I'm having this problem:

```
nodetool status -u cassandra -pw cassandra 
error: Authentication failed! Credentials required
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed! Credentials required
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.JMXPluggableAuthenticator.authenticationFailure(JMXPluggableAuthenticator.java:211)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.JMXPluggableAuthenticator.authenticate(JMXPluggableAuthenticator.java:163)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap$AccessFileCheckerAuthenticator.authenticate(ConnectorBootstrap.java:219)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.doNewClient(RMIServerImpl.java:232)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.newClient(RMIServerImpl.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$79(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub.newClient(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.getConnection(RMIConnector.java:2432)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:308)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeProbe.connect(NodeProbe.java:183)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeProbe.<init>(NodeProbe.java:150)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool$NodeToolCmd.connect(NodeTool.java:297)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool$NodeToolCmd.run(NodeTool.java:237)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.main(NodeTool.java:153)
```

My configuration is this:

```
/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password
cassandra cassandra

/opt/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.access
monitorRole   readonly
cassandra     readwrite
controlRole   readwrite \
          create javax.management.monitor.*,javax.management.timer.* \
          unregister

/etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh
LOCAL_JMX=no

if [ "$LOCAL_JMX" = "yes" ]; then
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=$JMX_PORT -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
else
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password"
```

Maybe someone else faced same problem?

Cassandra Version: 2.2.1
JAVA Version: 1.8.0_60

Answer (score 16):

Put the command at the end and the options at the beginning, like this:

`nodetool -u cassandra -pw cassandra status`

Comment: Yes, I realised this after the post. Thanks!