# Cassandra nodetool authentication

Tags: cassandra, jmx, datastax-enterprise

Using DataStax Enterprise, I password protected my JMX session by following the directions here: 
https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204226179-Step-by-step-instructions-for-securing-JMX-authentication-for-nodetool-utility-OpsCenter-and-JConsole

Unfortunately, I always get an Authentication error when attempting to connect.

I'm certain I'm using the right credentials, because I can use jmxconsole to connect to the server using the credentials I applied.

```
ubuntu@myServer:/etc/bps$ nodetool status -u cassandra -pw somepass
error: Authentication failed! Credentials required
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed! Credentials required
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.JMXPluggableAuthenticator.authenticationFailure(JMXPluggableAuthenticator.java:211)
.....
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039295/cassandra-nodetool-status-fails-with-credentials-required-after-enabling-rem/33040085#33040085

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to look at the command's help.  Don't just blindly follow the directions on the link above.  You have to supply the user name and password BEFORE you specify the command ....

```
ubuntu@cgcassdev-search-uswest2a-5d51a186:/etc/bps$ nodetool help
usage: nodetool [(-pwf <passwordFilePath> | --password-file <passwordFilePath>)]
        [(-h <host> | --host <host>)] [(-pw <password> | --password <password>)]
        [(-u <username> | --username <username>)] [(-p <port> | --port <port>)]
        <command> [<args>]
```

So this works:

```
ubuntu@myServer:/etc/bps$ nodetool -u cassandra -pw somepass status
```